# ¿Cómo bloqueo la pantalla o la computadora con javascript, jquery, php o jsp?

Tags: java, php, javascript, jquery, socket.io

Necesito crear una app como un control de ciber, que al terminar cierto tiempo la computadora se bloquee. ¿Alguna idea? Lo que necesito realmente es saber cómo bloqueo la pantalla. Sé que hay que usar sockets para la comunicación y así. Yo quiero saber cómo bloquear la pantalla y ya.

Denme ideas, el código lo puedo programar yo fácilmente, el problema es que no he encontrado nada online pues no sé cómo buscarlo.

**EDIT:**

La idea es que desde un móvil un usuario pueda asignar tiempo de uso (desbloquear) a un ordenador.
Puede ser una app cualquiera, en la que un smartphone por medio de su navegador pueda acceder a la app online y asignarle tiempo a una computadora. Cómo es posible?

Comment: con java probablemente se pueda, los demás lo veo difícil.

Comment: Mmmmmm, me imagino con un frame que cubra toda la pantalla. Es problema es que necesito que sea web, no puedo usar frames de java de escritorio (?

Comment: Que tenga conexión web no quiere decir que tengas que usar un marco de trabajo web como servlets o php. Creo que en este caso es mejor que sea nativo con C++, o C# que tienen acceso a las bibliotecas de windows. de todas formas has probado alguno que [ya esté hecho](http://www.cbm.com.ar/downloads.htm)?

Comment: Hola, @ArieCwHat No hay nada hecho con los requerimientos que se quieren. Los pongo en la pregunta. Dame 2 min porfa.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, tú lo que necesitas es una aplicación de escritorio instalada en cada computadora de tu ciber y que le puedas mandar a ejecutar comandos de manera remota. Además, tendrías una aplicación de escritorio o web instalada en una computadora que sirva para dar órdenes a las demás aplicaciones

Comment: Hola, @LuiggiMendoza, y cómo identificaría a qué computadora es a la que le daría órdenes?

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene respuestas muy amplias. Yo puedo explicarte una idea de cómo podría implementarse esto (digamos que una arquitectura de una de las posibles soluciones).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza cómo puedo contactarte?

Comment: Crea una sala de chat e invítame.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59312/discussion-between-user2930137-and-luiggi-mendoza).

Comment: Hola: Aquí tienes cómo bloquear la pantalla con un comando de windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745788/how-do-i-lock-a-windows-workstation-programmatically que es lo que dices que estabas buscando. El resto es hacer una aplicación en el pc que arranque esto cuando reciba (via socket u otro medio que dices que ya conoces) la orden desde el movil.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa esta documentación, la cosa va a nivel del sistema operativo y no del browser, de otro modo habría miles de sitios que te bloquearían el computador como "broma" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735788/locking-computer-remotely